# Custom directory in Joomla when using search engine friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I'm using the standard .htaccess file that comes with Joomla 2.5. Joomla is installed in the root directory and I'm using search engine friendly URLs.

Can I add something to the beginning of the .htaccess file that will check for my custom directory in the url and allow normal access without any url re-writing?

For example, if I wanted customdir/ as my directory with all of my custom pages and scripts I would link to something like http://mysite.com/customdir/customscript.php

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding these lines in the standard *Joomla* .htaccess file, inside the 2 comment lines below:

```
## Begin - Custom redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customdir        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !customscript\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* /customdir/customscript.php    [L]
## End - Custom redirects
```

Maps silently:

`http://mysite.com/customdir/` or

`http://mysite.com/customdir/anything/`

To:

`http://mysite.com/customdir/customscript.php`

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L]